# I have an array of Questions and Answers on serverside. How can I render these one by one in EJS template on click?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

My route:

```
app.get('/test', (req,res)=>{
  res.render('index.ejs',{qData: [{Q1},{Q2},...]});
})
```

How to render this qData on client side one by one on clicks? Suppose I have two buttons "Next" and "Previous" for rendering next and previous questions respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass information back and forth between client(browser/EJS rendered template) and server (node/route) to keep track of which question is being viewed. For example:

Route:

```
const questions = [Q1, Q2, Q3, ...];

// The URL for this route is like:
// http://localhost:3000/test/0
// Or:
// http://localhost:3000/test/1
// Where the last part tells us which question the user is on.
app.get('/test/:page', (req, res) => {
    // Pull the page parameter out of the request.
    let page = Number.parseInt(req.params.page) || 0;
    res.render('index.ejs', {
        qData: questions[page],
        page,
        pageMax: questions.length - 1
    });
});
```

Template:

```
<!-- Render your Question Data however you need to: -->
<div>
    <%- JSON.stringify(qData) %>
</div>

<!-- Pagination -->
<% if (page > 0) { %>
    <a href="/test/<%- page - 1 %>">Prev</a>
<% } %>

<% if (page < pageMax) { %>
    <a href="/test/<%- page + 1 %>">Next</a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I want to render the qData only once on client side and the questions change according to "next" and "pre" buttons. To clear my point suppose we have qData in javascript and It render each question  in 'innerHTML" on clicks. 
PS: Don't want to call server side each time for the questions